# How do I install drivers for a Netgear WNDA3100v2?

Tags: wireless, internet, netgear

I have a Netgear WNDA3100v2 usb wifi adapter, and I need to figure out how to install the drivers. I have the disc that came with the adapter. What do I need to install in order to use this on Ubuntu 14.0.4? And how do I install those programs without an internet connection?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1383708 This might get your Netgear up and running.

Comment: I get nothing after typing that in.

Comment: I do not believe so.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried typing that into the terminal and nothing happened. I don't know if that's what you wanted me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in and from the command line run:

```
iwconfig
```

You may need to reboot before the hardware can be identified by Ubuntu.

It should show up as *wlan0* if you have no other wifi adapter installed.

Netgear is typically supported in Ubuntu without the need for third party drivers.

To check your adapter performance, install *wavemon*:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wavemon
```

To run *wavemon*

```
wavemon
```

Their are other ways to monitor your signal strength but this one gives you and nice graphic display from the Terminal.

Comment: A `sudo apt-get update` is not necessary.